# How to fix TRANSACTION_REFUSED error in WooCommerce PayPal Payments plugin

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

Am using WooCommerce with WooCommerce PayPal Payments plugin, on checking out (live environment) am getting the error below;

**[UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY]** The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-TRANSACTION_REFUSED

To add on, sandbox works without any issue.

I will be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

TRANSACTION_REFUSED is not a technical problem, and so cannot be fixed. It is a decline by PayPal.

Have the customer use a different payment method, or contact PayPal for information about why the payment might have been declined.

Note that payments to your own production account are not permitted. If the payer information is at all connected to the receiving account, this is why it was declined.